Android Unit Test Fails in Cloned android architecture-template Project
In Android Studio, I run a unit test on unmodified code which has been cloned from the Android Developer Github repository. The project and test class build without errors, the test and subject class are in the same package, the application runs on an emulator, but the test fails with:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/myapp/data/DefaultMyDataItemTypeRepository 
com/myapp/data/DefaultMyDataItemTypeRepository exists in the expected package, and is visible when writing and compiling the test class. This error occurs when running the test, as a JUnit test.
I assume that a different classpath is used at compile vs test run, vs run, or I am misreading file locations. This is straight from Github, Android Starter Templates, so I did not simplify the code. Steps to reproduce and more details are below.
Reproduce

Clone the android project from Github and run the included script to make name changes:

 git clone https://github.com/android/architecture-templates.git --branch base
./customizer.sh com.myapp MyDataItemType MyApp

Open the project in Android Studio, clean and rebuild
I had to modify gradle/libs.versions.toml to solve a dagger/hilt issue. See:

I am struggling compiling Android project in Android Studio with Dagger/Hilt and Proguard
Unable to find method void org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmOptions.setUseIR(boolean)
hilt = "2.5.31 -> "2.52"
kotlin = "2.1.0" -> "2.0.21"
ksp = "2.1.0-1.0.29" -> "2.0.21-1.0.25"


Run the app as a sanity test, in my case it works

Run the unit test below, as a JUnit test. It fails with NoClassDefFoundError
In com.myapp.data.DefaultMyDataItemTypeRepositoryTest:


    @Test
    fun myDataItemTypes_newItemSaved_itemIsReturned() = runTest {
        //Next line throws the error
        val repository = DefaultMyDataItemTypeRepository(FakeMyDataItemTypeDao())
        ...
}

Dev Tools

Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1
Build #AI-242.21829.142.2421.12409432, built on September 24, 2024
Runtime version: 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Toolkit: sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
Windows 11.0
Kotlin plugin: K2 mode (Beta)
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Concurrent GC, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry:
ide.experimental.ui=true
i18n.locale=


Up-to-date for Android Gradle Plugin version 8.7.3

Stack trace:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/myapp/data/DefaultMyDataItemTypeRepository

    at com.myapp.data.DefaultMyDataItemTypeRepositoryTest$myDataItemTypes_newItemSaved_itemIsReturned$1.invokeSuspend(DefaultMyDataItemTypeRepositoryTest.kt:37)
    at com.myapp.data.DefaultMyDataItemTypeRepositoryTest$myDataItemTypes_newItemSaved_itemIsReturned$1.invoke(DefaultMyDataItemTypeRepositoryTest.kt)
    at com.myapp.data.DefaultMyDataItemTypeRepositoryTest$myDataItemTypes_newItemSaved_itemIsReturned$1.invoke(DefaultMyDataItemTypeRepositoryTest.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$2$1$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:318)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestDispatcher.processEvent$kotlinx_coroutines_test(TestDispatcher.kt:24)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineScheduler.tryRunNextTaskUnless$kotlinx_coroutines_test(TestCoroutineScheduler.kt:99)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$2$1$workRunner$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:327)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:280)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersJvmKt.createTestResult(TestBuildersJvm.kt:10)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(TestBuilders.kt:310)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(TestBuilders.kt:168)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0$default(TestBuilders.kt:160)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.myapp.data.DefaultMyDataItemTypeRepositoryTest.myDataItemTypes_newItemSaved_itemIsReturned(DefaultMyDataItemTypeRepositoryTest.kt:36)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myapp.data.DefaultMyDataItemTypeRepository
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 50 more

